# Эмуляция работы BackSpace

Tags: javascript

Предположим, что на странице расположен один input, который заполняем текстом и кнопка при нажатии на которую определяется позиция каретки в input и передается переменной 'carret'. В коде ниже, в input.value передается удаленный элемент, вместо строки без удаленного элемента(понятно, что splice возвращает удаленный из массива элемент). Как передать в input.value строку, без удаленного символа.

```
    if( e.target.dataset.key == 'Backspace'){
      let inputValue = document.querySelector('.i-1').value;

      document.querySelector('.i-1').value = inputValue.split('').splice(carret-1, 1).join('');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
if( e.target.dataset.key == 'Backspace'){
  let inputValue = document.querySelector('.i-1').value;
  let arr = inputValue.split('');
  arr.splice(carret-1, 1);
  document.querySelector('.i-1').value = arr.join('');
}
```