# Проверка input-a на фокус

Tags: javascript

Есть некая функция 'addToInput', которая должна содержать условие по проверке наличия фокуса на input-e. Как правильно осуществлять такую проверку:

```
function addToInput(whatAdd, backspace = false) {
   if(document.querySelector('.i-1').onfocus){ // <--------------
     // .......
   }else{
     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128861/%d0%ad%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-backspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.querySelector('.i-1') == document.activeElement) {
```

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log((document.querySelector('.i-1') == document.activeElement) ? "yes" : "no");
}, 100);
```

```html
<input class="i-1" />
<input class="i-2" />
```